# Unable to install Ubuntu on a 32 GB eMMC storage Laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, bios, emmc

I have a laptop which came with pre-installed Windows 10. It has 32 GB eMMC storage, 2GB RAM and the processor is a Celeron Dual Core. Constant Windows updates have made it impossible to use. I wanted to install Ubuntu onto it so that it's at least usable.

I created a bootable USB drive, but the boot menu or BIOS did not recognize it. I used Rufus and balenaEtcher to make the device bootable, but none of them worked. I then tried installing Windows 8.1 (using balenaEtcher to make the bootable device) on the system and it got installed just fine. The name of my device is Asus EBOOK 203MA. I want to use Linux on the system as I think I will have a lot more control over my system.

Is it even possible to install Ubuntu or any Linux OS onto this system? If it is possible, please help me out.

Comment: Hey Shanks! Since your device has low-end specifications, I suggest you to install [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) instead of Ubuntu. [Lubuntu is a lightweight Linux distribution based on Ubuntu, using the LXQt desktop environment in place of Ubuntu's GNOME desktop.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) Getting back to your question, please let us know the steps you followed to make the bootable USB drive. Also, did you [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu)?  When you reply to my comment, please tag me like this (such that I'll be notified): @RandomPerson

Comment: @RandomPerson Sir I am so incredibly sorry and embarrassed. I don't even know how to reply to you as I think I have lost all my credibility. I am incredibly sorry for this late reply.
To Answer your query, I used Rufus and Balena etcher to make to bootable device but none of that worked. But then I tried installing Windows 8.1  (using Balena to make the bootable device) on the System and it got installed just fine. 
The name of my device is Asus EBOOK 203MA.
I want to use Linux on the System as then I think I will have a lot more control over my system.
And Sir once again I am really Sorry

Comment: Please don't be sorry. It's OK to reply late. BTW, did you [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) and which version of Ubuntu did you use to make bootable USB drive? Don't forget to tag me if you reply to my comment.

Comment: @RandomPerson I did not verify the ISO per se, but I tried using the same bootable drive on another machine(HCL Me Laptop from 2010, 2GB RAM,320 GB HDD) and that worked.